# Retrieving M3U8 via PHP vs. via Website gives different session variables

Tags: php, session, variables, m3u8

I'm trying to scrape a website (www.glturk.com).
When I run the below link via a browser:

```
http://www.glturk.com/ajax.aspx?stream=live&type=free&ppoint=ATVTurkiye_LR
```

I get the following response:

```
http://38.117.88.248:7777/ATVTurkiye_LR.m3u8?user=sglsxxdewfiduaqygnbfnqwcuc55&session=e0e8f5e6dbfb83be9e4f1155454b43d14130b7e79528a6fbe8dcb832c9f2cef0fbecdaf0092c93ab9826978c8d46626c20ba4293a32569e6e7cfbbd9d61c69ad
```

The above M3U8 link works perfectly in that instance.

But, if I try to replicate this via a PHP file, I get a very similar result, but that m3u8 link does not work?!

```
<?php
   $channelURL= 'http://www.glturk.com/ajax.aspx?stream=live&type=free&ppoint=ATVTurkiye_LR';
   $actualLink = file_get_contents($channelURL, TRUE);
   echo $actualLink;
?>
```

The result I get is:

```
http://38.117.88.249:7777/ATVTurkiye_LR.m3u8?user=sglspoqmpdi2tltn0lynorytlnvi&session=08e5fd64dca2f17d9e4f1155454b43d136fa14cb989a57687b29865e85d60962253ac665a78595d7c5529895b22236c2f32018226b4a15e9b8327f16597d3505
```

This m3u8 does not work though, I can't understand why.

Working (via direct link through browser):

```
http://38.117.88.248:7777/ATVTurkiye_LR.m3u8?user=sglsxxdewfiduaqygnbfnqwcuc55&session=e0e8f5e6dbfb83be9e4f1155454b43d14130b7e79528a6fbe8dcb832c9f2cef0fbecdaf0092c93ab9826978c8d46626c20ba4293a32569e6e7cfbbd9d61c69ad
```

Not Working (via PHP):

```
http://38.117.88.249:7777/ATVTurkiye_LR.m3u8?user=sglspoqmpdi2tltn0lynorytlnvi&session=08e5fd64dca2f17d9e4f1155454b43d136fa14cb989a57687b29865e85d60962253ac665a78595d7c5529895b22236c2f32018226b4a15e9b8327f16597d3505
```

Any advise would be appreciated :) Thank you!

Comment: It is likely that this behavior is intentional, to prevent streaming links from being shared. Contact the operators of that site for details.

Comment: It works for me. The session parameter looks like a string that's generated randomly each time. But when I use `file_get_contents` on that URL I get two lines in the response: `#EXTM3U` and `#EXT-X-VERSION:3`.

Comment: I get a result too, but does the generated m3u8 actually run if you try it?

Comment: Also, note that im running the PHP off a remote host (not locally)