# url_encode with WGET in PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, web, wget, m3u8

This question is following another topic I had asked earlier, which nobody was able to assist:

[Retrieving M3U8 via PHP vs. via Website gives different session variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38214758/retrieving-m3u8-via-php-vs-via-website-gives-different-session-variables)

So now I'm trying to WGET the same website via PHP, but I believe I need to encode the url. When I try the below command, nothing gets downloaded:

```
<?php
    exec("wget --header='Host: www.glturk.com' http://www.glturk.com/ajax.aspx?stream=live&type=free&ppoint=TRT1_LR");
?>
```

I get an empty file that downloads: 'ajax.aspx-stream=live', which suggests maybe the url isn't being read properly?

How can I encode that link? I've also tried:

```
<?php
    $encoded = urlencode("http://www.glturk.com/ajax.aspx?stream=live&type=free&ppoint=TRT1_LR");
    exec("wget --header='Host: www.glturk.com' $encoded");
?>
```

Any idea? I keep getting empty files downloaded? Thanks for your help!

Comment: i some how think they may not want you scraping their content

Answer (score 1):

The characters `?` and `&` have special meaning to the shell, so you need to quote the URL.

```
exec("wget --header='Host: www.glturk.com' 'http://www.glturk.com/ajax.aspx?stream=live&type=free&ppoint=TRT1_LR'");
```

The proper function for escaping shell arguments is [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php), not `urlencode`. So you could also do:

```
$encoded = escapeshellarg("http://www.glturk.com/ajax.aspx?stream=live&type=free&ppoint=TRT1_LR");
exec("wget --header='Host: www.glturk.com' $encoded");
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this works, but the outputting m3u8 once again is invalid - which is what my previous question was in my initial post. I dunno why it happens... I can get the m3u8 fine, but it won't run... If I run the http://www.glturk.com/ajax.aspx?stream=live&type=free&ppoint=TRT1_LR link directly, the resulting m3u8 works perfectly..

Comment: I just commented in the other question that I can't reproduce your problem with the returned URL.

Answer (score 0):

curl

```
$url = "http://www.glturk.com/ajax.aspx?stream=live&type=free&ppoint=TRT1_LR";
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$output = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 
echo $output;
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this works, but the outputting m3u8 once again is invalid - which is what my previous question was in my initial post. I dunno why it happens... I can get the m3u8 fine, but it won't run... If I run the [link]http://www.glturk.com/ajax.aspx?stream=live&type=free&ppoint=TRT1_LR[/link] link directly, the resulting m3u8 works perfectly..